# LINUX: How do I search for a string in a different directory?

Tags: linux, search, terminal, directory, grep

I am working on the Linux terminal and I want to know how to search for c files in a certain directory. I have it working for the current directory but how do I do it for the directory usr/

for the current directory i did

```
grep -l "main" *.c
```

so I'd like to know how to search in the /usr directory without changing the directory first. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You should just be able to prefix the directory name you want to the file pattern you want to search.

```
grep -l "main" /usr/*.c
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

`find /usr/ -name "*.c"`

if it is just the C files in the /usr/ directory you are after.